# less search: show match with context before match (within less)

Tags: man, less

I would like to modify the search behavior when inside `less`: By default next match is shown at the very top line. Instead show me next match of `word` at 5th line of screen/ show 4 lines before match. Like so:

```
yadda yadda
yadda
more yadda
more of the yadda
Some sentence with word (<-- match!)
yadda goes on
```

This is somewhat similar to `grep -B4`: print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines.

`Less` is by default my manpages pager.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type `-j5` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to set the target line for searches to 5 (the default setting is `1` which is the top line).

To make this the default, add `-j5` to the default less options. One way to do that is to include `-j5` in the `LESS` environment variable set e.g. in your `.profile` or `.environment`. Another way is to put

```
#env
LESS = -j5
```

in `~/.lesskey` and run the command `lesskey`.

Comment: Thank you. Now that you me point me to it: You can position the screen relative to the match depending on your screen size. `.1` puts the match at the first tenth of the screen height. Thanks again!